# Webpack-dev-server keeps trying to reconnect

Tags: angular, webpack, browser, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I'm working on an Angular project with a small group of people, and it seems I'm the only one with this issue. All of us work on branches which are based of the same main branch, which has the frontend environment.

Whenever I open a browser console and refresh the project's compiled and rendered page, I'm met with a wall of [webpack-dev-server] logs being emitted overtime. This in turn slows down the load of the page, and makes it unbearably slow to do any small adjustments in the code. I've posted a screenshot of the console below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GnYu.png). If I try refreshing the page without the console open, everything loads in much quicker and without any issues. Sadly, "just close the console before refreshing" won't work because I need the mobile view of the page.

Things I do know that might help:

- This happens on both Edge and Chrome. Haven't tried it on other browsers.
- This does NOT happen on my pc, when I connect with localhost through Opera
- This does NOT happen on other pcs with same the same project.
- This happens in other angular projects.
- npm Install & Update doesn't seem to change anything on the issue.
- Webpack version: 5.74.0
- Webpack-dev-server version: 4.11.0
- I'm using visual studio and Intellij as IDE
- After compiling the project using npm start, new errors appeared. Second image for reference

**UPDATE**

This reconnection loop only starts to happen after I turn on the mobile view through Browser's Dev console. If I never turn on the mobile device view, refreshing the page doesn't take much time. If I turn on the mobile device view, the loop begins and each refresh of the page takes ages. If I turn off the device view AND restart the console, the loop seems to stop (no more console logs from image 1). There seems to be new errors, but those PROBABLY are caused by the fact, that I didn't set up the backend and the local database correctly. Might be unrelated, but I'll add an image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaduJ.png) for clarity and just in case.

Any advice would be helpful, I'll gladly add any needed information.

[Reconnection Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GnYu.png)

[npm start errors - HTTP request to non existent backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaduJ.png)

Comment: Does this happen on both IntelliJ and Visual Studio, or only on one of them? Is it Visual Studio Code, or the big Visual Studio? You can try to start your project from the command prompt instead of clicking the start button from the IDE. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: I usually use ng serve from the terminal level to start the angular server. Right now I've decided to use npm start, and I've gained some additional errors which might narrow down the issue. I'll add the new info to the description.

Comment: Talk to your other teammates and ask one of them to give you the contents of their `.vscode` folder. While you are at it, ask them to search for `proxyConfig` in their `angular.json` file and give you the path, and also the contents of the file that they find there.

Comment: Also, try disabling all the extensions that you have, and also try with another browser, Firefox for example. Make sure to have all the extensions turned off.

Comment: I hadn't have time to ask one of my teammates for the IDE files, but I did have time to get a clean install of Opera. For now it seems like the reconnection loop doesn't happen on Opera. I'll look into what extensions I have on both Edge and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It's a half year old post, but still relevant.

"..This reconnection loop only starts to happen after I turn on the mobile view through Browser's Dev console.."

Same happens to me with latest VS Code and Chrome (Version: 112.0.5615.121) on Win10 with an angular 14 app, after I turn on the mobile view then refresh the browser.

What I tried:

- set up host at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts as 127.0.0.1         localhost
- npm start instead of ng serve (npm start runs ng serve so it makes no sense in my case)
- set up and grant permission for a workspace folder in devtools settings (workspace folder is the root folder of angular app)

won't helped.

But to my surprise **with Microsoft Edge** Version: 112.0.1722.48 **it works without reconnection loop**, even in mobile view.

My installed chrome extensions are:

- Drive 3.5
- Google docs 1.60.0
- JSON Formatter 0.7.1
- ModHeader - Modify HTTP headers 4.3.2

Answer (score -1):

I think the root cause probably was that on the Network Tab the throttling was set up to slow 3G network some reason and that has remained. Also coused slow network traffic in mobile and in normal view when development mode was opened.

[see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSSO7.png)